# Get neighbors for N dimensional square

Tags: algorithms

I need some algorithm to get neighbours of **`x`** vertex of **`N`** dimensional square.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Is this a question about the language Mathematica, or about mathematics? If the latter, this is not the right SE group. (2) How are you representing `x`? By `n` coordinates that are either 0 or 1? If so, the `n` neighbors are each obtained by reversing one coordinate.

Comment: (1) This is a question connected with graph theories, also with mathematics and algorithms 
(2) x is the number of vertex. It is decimal number
Thanks for comment, I think I found the answer of my quesiton while answering to yours)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int getNeigbhourOfSquareVertex(int x, int j) {
        return x ^ pow(2,j);

    }
```

This is what I was searching for. XOR with `j` pow of `2` I can get the `j`-th neighbor.

Comment: what is this i dont even ....

Comment: @wonko: It would be more productive if you flagged such posts for moderator attention.

Comment: @Jacob This answer was posted by the question asker, so presumably it is a satisfactory answer to him. I don't see a reason to flag the answer. It may be reasonable to question the on-topicness of the question.

Comment: On second thought, this actually works and is kinda cool. The problem was more that the original question was not well written.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ in a hypercube with edge length $c$ the the neighboring vertices are $(x_1 \pm c,x_2,...,x_n), (x_1,x_2 \pm c,...,x_n), ..., (x_1,x_2,...,x_n \pm c)$ where the $ \pm $ depends on which vertex $x$ is.  For example, the neighbors of $(0,0,...,0)$ could be $(c,0,...,0), (0,c,...,0),...,(0,0,...,c)$

Comment: Thanks for answer but I was searching for a little bit another answer. Maybe I declared the question not well.